# Totally Transparent for a QFrame

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt Creator 4.5.2 (Qt 5.9.5, GCC 7.3.0 64-bit) and running on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have a QT MainWindow (a QWidget) which is QRectF(0,0,480,800). On the MainWindow, there is a QFrame which is QRectF(0,60,480,400). I would like to have the QFrame totally transparent. In other words, I would like to see the display on the Desktop of the PC behind the QFrame frame but not see the Desktop behind other parts of the QT MainWindow.

Is it possible?
I have googled a lot and did not find a good solution.

I tried:

```
setStyleSheet("QFrame{border: None; background-color: transparent;}");
```

or

```
setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent; QFrame{border: None; background-color: transparent;}");
```

or

```
setStyleSheet("QFrame{border: None; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,100;}");
```

Neither of them work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working for me

```
widget->setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;");
widget->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);   //No windowing
widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground); // No background
```

Comment: For more help visit these threads... https://forum.qt.io/search?term=transparent%20background&in=posts&matchWords=all&sortBy=relevance&sortDirection=desc&showAs=posts

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget

Comment: Did not really work. I still could not see the desktop part. Instead, I saw the previous screen of my application. My application has multiple screen.

Answer (score 1):

When you add QFrame to QMainWindow and set transparent background to QFrame, QMainWindow remains filled with some color. You need to set transparent style to QFrame:

```
frame->setStyleSheet("border: none; background: transparent;");
```

And than set attribute to QMainWindow:

```
mainWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

Comment: Did not  really work. I still could not see the desktop part. Instead, I saw the previous screen of my application. My application has multiple screen.